# import of css using webpack returns an array not object

Tags: css, reactjs, module, webpack

I have reviewed almost every question/answer on the site that relates to this but am unable to get things to work.

I am importing a .css file within my react code, as follows:

```
import theme from '../stylesheets/autosuggest.css';
```

but when I console.log the theme object, I get an array, not an object.

File autosuggest.css contains:

```
.suggestionsContainer ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

My webpack config contains:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "css-loader?modules=true"
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: "style-loader!raw-loader!sass-loader)
  },
```

The output of:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(theme))
```

is the following:

```
[[629,"._1iN32ylkX4V29XkoF-ztbe ul {\n  list-style: none;\n}",""]]
```

I am completely lost here and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For css you would normally load them into your index.html like;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/autosuggest.css">
```

Then setup the webpack cssloader to combine multiple css into one, or just move the one to your dist folder. My webpack config looks like this;

```js
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const minimize = process.argv.indexOf('--no-minimize') === -1 ? true : false;
let plugins = [];

plugins.push(new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css', {allChunks: true}));
plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('lib', 'lib.js', Infinity));
if (minimize) plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({include: /lib\.js/, minimize: true}));

const ROOT_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname);
const SRC_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'ui-src', 'app.jsx');
const DIST_PATH = path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'ui-dist');

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    app: SRC_PATH,
    lib: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-hammerjs', 'react-mixin', 'redux', 'screenfull', 'whatwg-fetch', 'react-redux', 'react-modal']
  },

  output: {
    path: DIST_PATH,
    filename: 'app.js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {presets:['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']}
      },
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')},
      {test: /\.(png|jpg|ico|gif)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.(html|pdf)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'}
    ]
  },
  plugins,
  resolve: {extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']}
};
```

In this case I have the following in my index.html;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer. But here is my problem. I have to pass down as a parameter the styles in the css file. Like so:                              `<Autosuggest
          .......
   theme={theme} />` where 'theme' is got from the line:                              `import theme from '../stylesheets/autosuggest.css';` In this situation 'theme' is expected to be an object, but I get an array instead. That is my problem.

Comment: Mark, I got it to work. I changed my webpack config for css loaders to the following: `{
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1'
      }`  I wonder if the importLoaders=1 setting made the difference, although I do not see how.  Thanks again for your help.